# Non existence of preferred Horizontal subspace on a bundle

Tags: fibre-bundles, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

If I choose a principal bundle, let us say $G\rightarrow P \rightarrow B$, with $G=U(1)$, $P=S^1 \times S^1$ and $B=S^1$. Can I follow the identity element of the group over a curve at the base. How isn't this equivalent to a preferred Horizontal subspace (and hence a canonical connection) ?

Comment: You're confusion probably comes from the misleading idea that a principal G-bundle is a bundle with fiber G. In fact a principal G-bundle is a bundle whose fiber is a space with a simply transitive G-action. Identifying it with G is exactly equivalent to choosing a point in it. So the only obstruction to triviality of a principal G-bundle is precisely the existence of a section.

Comment: Well, S1 x S1 is trivial... Rather, look at the bundle of unit tangent vectors to the 2-sphere. It has an action of S1 by rotating a tangent vector by $\theta$, but it does not admit a global section by the hairy ball theorem !

Comment: @NicolasTholozan your first comment makes a lot more sens to me now, merci !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A trivial principal bundle, $P= G\times B\to B$ has a preferred connection (which is also flat). There is an obvious map $B\to \{1\}\times B\subset P$ and you can take as horizontal bundle the image of its differential.
2. If your principal  bundle $P\to B$ is not trivial, but is trivializable, i.e. exists a section $\sigma:B\to P$, then you can use this section to trivialize it, i.e. construct a isomorphism with the trivial bundle,  $\Phi_\sigma: P\overset{\simeq}{\to} G\times B$. Over $G\times B$ you have the preferred connection of item 1) and you can use $\Phi_\sigma$ to pull it back to $P$.
   You now have a connection on $P$, but the latter depends on the choice of the trivialization $\sigma$. How many choices do you have? Well, the space of sections is acted transitively and freely by (hence is in bijection with)  the gauge group $\mathcal G(P) \simeq  \operatorname{Maps}(B, G)$ as you can alter $\sigma$ by multiplying it with an element of $\operatorname{Maps}(B, G)$. This tells you that the possible choices that you have are $\mathcal{G}(P)$.
   Notice that all these connections will be flat.

3. If  the principal bundle $P$ is not trivializable, then you cannot apply any of the above and you have a space of connection which is an *affine* space modelled over $\Omega^1(B; \operatorname{ad} (P))$ where $\operatorname{ad} (P) = P\times_{\operatorname{ad}}\mathfrak{g} $ is the bundle associated to the adjoint action $\operatorname{ad}:G\to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ of $G$ on its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.
   As an example of non-trivializable bundle you can take $P$ equal to the bundle of oriented orthonormal frames of the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{S}^2$ (after you choose an orientation for $\mathbb{S}^2$ of course); this is an $\mathbb{S}^1\simeq \operatorname{SO}(2)$ bundle over $\mathbb{S}^2$ which does not admit any section.

As a side note, even in this case the gauge group $\mathcal{G}(P)$ acts on the set of connections, however it is no more in bijection with $\operatorname{Maps}(B,G)$ but instead with $\Gamma(B; \operatorname{Ad}(P))$ i.e. sections of the bundle associated to the action $\operatorname{Ad}: G\to \operatorname{Aut}(G) $, $\operatorname{Ad}(g)\cdot p = gpg^{-1}$.
In the case of a trivial bundle $\operatorname{Ad}(P)\simeq G\times B$ hence in item 2)  we were able to  identify $\mathcal{G}(P)$  with $\operatorname{Maps}(B, G)$.

Comment: How do you create a chart of the frame bundle over $S^2\{1 point}$ without talking of a smooth gluing of the fibers ?

Comment: Maybe this example will help you clearing out things. 
Consider $P =\mathbb{S}^3$ as the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^2$; then multiplication by $U(1)$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ preserves $\mathbb{S}^3$ thus we have an action over $P$ which you can check is free. 
Therefore (see Bredon's book "introduction to compact transformation groups") the orbit map $P\to P/U(1)$ is a principal bundle. This map is also known as the Hopf map, and $P/U(1)$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$.
$P\neq U(1)\times \mathbb{S}^2$ therefore $P$ cannot be a trivial principal bundle.

Comment: When I wrote $P\neq U(1)\times \mathbb{S}^2$ I mean $P$ is *not diffeomorphic* to $U(1)\times \mathbb{S}^2$, not just that they are different as sets. And when I say that $P$ cannot be a trivial principal bundle I mean cannot be *isomorphic to* a trivial principal bundle. This is because if it was isomorphic then $P$ would be diffeomorphic to $U(1)\times \mathbb{S}^2$

Consequently, $P$ is not trivializable and does not admit any section. 

Regarding gauge transformations,  since $U(1)$ is commutative, these can be identified with maps from the base $P/U(1) \to U(1)$.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot.

Comment: Different fields will of course have different conventions, but, while using $\operatorname{Ad}$ for the action of a group on itself by inner automorphisms is reasonably common—I myself use $\operatorname{Int}$, but it's far from universal—I think that, between $\operatorname{Ad}$ and $\operatorname{ad}$, Lie-group theorists will almost always use the latter only for the action of $\mathfrak g$ on itself by derivations, and the former for the action of $G$ on $\mathfrak g$ by automorphisms.